# After installing Phoniebox/RPi-Jukebox-RFID no sound

Tags: audio, raspberry-pi, raspbian, alsa

I have a RaspberryPi 3B+ running Raspberry Pi OS (32-bit) Lite (Minimal image based on Debian Buster). I added [this adafruit speaker bonnet](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-speaker-bonnet-for-raspberry-pi) and hooked up two 3W speakers. I followed [these instructions](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-speaker-bonnet-for-raspberry-pi/raspberry-pi-usage) to setup the amp with the speakers; basically running this command:

```
curl -sS https://raw.githubusercontent.com/adafruit/Raspberry-Pi-Installer-Scripts/master/i2samp.sh | bash
```

After finishing the installation and a couple reboots, the speaker test was successful and I heard the "front-left / front-right" audio.

Now I was ready to install `/RPi-Jukebox-RFID` using this command:

```
cd; rm buster-install-*; wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/MiczFlor/RPi-Jukebox-RFID/master/scripts/installscripts/buster-install-default.sh; chmod +x buster-install-default.sh; ./buster-install-default.sh
```

It took some time to complete the installation but I left every setting pretty much as default. I entered mt wifi and spotify credentials but other than that there was no customization. I left `PCM` as the audio output.
However, after the completed installation I have no more sound, BUT: I do hear a startup sound! After that it is just static.
If I re-run the speaker test `speaker-test -c2` I don't get any sound output anymore.

I checked the following:

- `cat settings/Audio_iFace_Name` outputs `PCM`
- `amixer scontrols` outputs `Simple mixer control 'PCM',0`
- `aplay -l` outputs:

  ```
   **** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
   card 0: sndrpihifiberry [snd_rpi_hifiberry_dac], device 0: HifiBerry DAC HiFi pcm5102a-hifi-0 [HifiBerry DAC HiFi pcm5102a-hifi-0]
     Subdevices: 0/1
     Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
  ```

I also tried [this troubleshooting](https://github.com/MiczFlor/RPi-Jukebox-RFID/wiki/HiFiBerry-Soundcard-Details) and added the following to `/etc/mpd.conf`

```
audio_output {
        enabled         "yes"
        type            "alsa"
        name            "HiFiBerry DAC+ Lite"
        device          "hifiberry"
        auto_resample   "no"
        auto_channels   "no"
        auto_format     "no"
        dop             "no"
}
```

Nothing brought back audio for me.

I also re-ran the installation script posted above, which I used to initially get the speakers going. Still no sound. At this point, I have no clue what is blocking my audio... Any ideas or pointers are greatly appreciated. Thank you very much :-)

Comment: You might get some help on sister site [raspberrypi](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/), though I didn't spot any similar problems.

Comment: Thanks. I will post my question over there as well :-) I have no idea where to start troubleshooting... Already did a brand new installation and the same thing happened again. No Audio after phoniebox installation, even though I had audio before.